# Variance of a random effect in Cox PH

Tags: variance, frailty

I want to fit a Cox PH model with random effect (Gamma frailty). Here is an example with 'kidney catheter' data set:

```
    > library(survival) 
    > data(kidney) 
    > fit <- coxph(Surv(time, status)~ age + sex + disease + frailty(id), kidney) 
    > fit

        Call:
        coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ age + sex + disease + frailty(id),
            data = kidney)

                    coef     se(coef) se2    Chisq DF p
        age          0.00318 0.0111   0.0111  0.08 1  7.8e-01
        sex         -1.48314 0.3582   0.3582 17.14 1  3.5e-05
        diseaseGN    0.08796 0.4064   0.4064  0.05 1  8.3e-01
        diseaseAN    0.35079 0.3997   0.3997  0.77 1  3.8e-01
        diseasePKD  -1.43111 0.6311   0.6311  5.14 1  2.3e-02
        frailty(id)                           0.00 0  9.3e-01

        Iterations: 6 outer, 28 Newton-Raphson
             Variance of random effect= 5e-07   I-likelihood = -179.1
        Degrees of freedom for terms= 1 1 3 0
        Likelihood ratio test=17.6  on 5 df, p=0.00342  n= 76

    > fit$history[[1]]$theta
      [1] 5e-09
```

Does the `fit$history[[1]]$theta` returns the variance of random
effect? Why is the value different?

Comment: I remember I asked exactly the same question to Terry Therneau, the author of coxph(), a few months ago. Unfortunately, he has been vague... He just answered "I recommend using the coxme function for random effects models.  It is much more mature than the frailty additions."

Comment: Just a further note: I have noticed that the value given in the output (5e-07) is the last value written in 'fit?history?frailty?history'

Comment: I also asked Terry Therneau, he gave me same answer. Yes, the value given in the output (5e-07) is the last value written in  'fit$history$frailty$history'. But why is it different, any kind of algorithmic problem or others?